# How to remove one class value from a two part class setup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
if((String(parent).length > 0) && (String(this.className).length > 0)) {
```

where this.className contains the value "top currentMenu"

Using this.className name, I need a means of removing from this.className, "currentMenu" ONLY using jQuery, so that the end result for this.className is just "top".

Comment: Side note: you don't need `String(this.className).length`.  The `className` property is already a string so you don't need to explicitly create a new string from it.  Just use `this.className.length`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is simply:

```
$(this).removeClass('currentMenu')
```

Reference: [`.removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)

---

In plain JavaScript you can do something like:

```
function removeClass(node, cls) {
    if(node && node.className && node.className.indexOf(cls) >= 0) {
        var pattern = new RegExp('\\s*' + cls + '\\s*');
        node.className = node.className.replace(pattern, ' ');
    }
}
```

Or I don't understand your problem :)

Comment: hi felix, tried this but didn't work. I think I need to actually use this.className and then strip out of this the "currentMenu" class name only.

Comment: @tonsils: You mean you tried `$(this).removeClass()` ? This definitely works, you must be doing something wrong. Can you post more code? In which context are you doing this? Don't forget to pass `this` into `$()` before you call a jQuery function.

Comment: is there anyway achieving your removeClass function with simple jQuery by passing in the second parameter only?

Comment: @tonsils: `removeClass` is the simple jQuery solution. The rest in my function is just string processing and jQuery won't help you here.